# Force JRE to run applet from local jar files

Tags: jar, proxy, applet, java

I am dealing with a corporate web app which cannot be modified. It uses Java applets to hook into smart cards for authentication. All works fine on an open network but this particular site is a secure environment utilising a very locked down proxy which prevents download of JAR files, hence the app doesn't work. For most pages it uses a single applet, so by dropping that JAR in lib/applet it will load it from there instead of downloading.

However on 1 crucial page, 4 JAR files are required for various purposes (they actually are, it's not just Java overload for the sake of it). I put the JAR containing the initially executed applet class into lib/applet and the rest in lib/ext, but the browser/JRE continue to try and download all 4 of them every time.

I can't modify the secure proxy config, or the HTML of the web app. Is there a way I can configure the JRE to always use a local JAR for specific classes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are hitting the sandbox firewall.  The docs state that sandbox applets cannot access client resources:

> They cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem,
>   executable files, system clipboard, and printers.

Since it cannot access local resources, it is trying to get what it needs via network connections to the host it came from (which is its only authorized source).

Getting an applet to access the local filesystem can get complicated if the applet was not loaded from the local filesystem:

> Applets that are loaded from the local file system (from a directory in the user's CLASSPATH) have none of the restrictions that applets loaded over the network do.

More info: [Applet Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wondered if it might be an access control issue, so put an entry in java.policy to give everything access to everything. Made no difference unfortunately.